# How print a PDF without the DRAFT watermark

Tags: pdf, printer, printing, latex, tex

I have this PDF file that has a gigantic DRAFT watermark on every single page. My teacher handed us his version of the printed pdf and it says on paper where it is printed from **but** on his version the DRAFT watermark is missing. When I print from the same page as his, the draft watermark is there.

I should mention that he owns everything, including the original TEX files for the PDF. Could it be that he explicitly removes the DRAFT before he prints?

Is there a way to print this PDF without the watermark or is that impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You could open the PDF on an editor like [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?loc=en&product=acrobat_pro) -you can download and install a trial version- or [PDFedit](http://pdfedit.cz/) (an open source, free editor that works on Linux and Windows that I haven't tried myself), but if the PDF is protected you may not be able to remove the watermark.

Also, I would ask the professor if it is ok to remove the watermark as it may have something to do with copyright.